# How can I pass paramters to the fun CompositionLocalProvider(vararg values: ProvidedValue<*>,...) in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A is the source code of Android Studio.

The Code B is from the offical sample project [here](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/article/PostContent.kt).

I can't understand fully why the author can pass these paramters `LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium` to the function `CompositionLocalProvider((vararg values: ProvidedValue<*>, ...)`.

You know that we separate paramters with comma normally.

**Code A**

```
@OptIn(InternalComposeApi::class)
fun CompositionLocalProvider(vararg values: ProvidedValue<*>, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    currentComposer.startProviders(values)
    content()
    currentComposer.endProviders()
}
```

**Code B**

```
 CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(
                        id = R.string.article_post_min_read,
                        formatArgs = arrayOf(
                            metadata.date,
                            metadata.readTimeMinutes
                        )
                    ),
                    style = typography.caption
                )
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample uses [infix function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#infix-notation) which allows to use alternative notation for invoking a function - without a dot and parentheses. You can translate the above code to:

```kotlin
LocalContentAlpha.provides(ContentAlpha.medium)
```

`CompositionLocalProvider` in this example actually receives only a single `ProvidedValue<*>` parameter, which is returned by this `provides()` function.

You can read about `provides()` function [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/ProvidableCompositionLocal#provides(kotlin.Any)). As you can see, it has `infix` modifier.